# Python code test in interview for junior dev

Tags: python, dictionary

I went for a junior python developer interview this morning and had to come up with a more pythonic way of representing the following code.

```
dict = {}
for i in range(a, b):
    if i % c == d:
        dict[i] = i/c
```

I didn't really know the answer what do you think he was looking for out of curiosity.

Comment: You may get help with this over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess most python devs would go with a dict comprehension.  And we would avoid to name a variable `dict` because it shadows the built-in type.

```
dict_ = {i: i/c for i in range(a,b) if i % c == d}
```

They might also be impressed if you can find a way to rewrite it (hint: the result has some parallels with [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)).  But I doubt the interviewer would expect a junior python dev to see this possibility - they probably were just hoping to see whether you comprehend comprehensions.

Comment: Also mentioning something about a possible `ZeroDivisionError` when `c = 0` could be extra points.

Comment: Using `divmod`: `{i: res[0] for i, res in ((i, divmod(i, c)) for i in range(a, b)) if res[1] == d}`. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Mattias I think you can exploit the fact that the elements of the range which will satisfy the conditional are evenly spaced (i.e. in a start:stop:step, like a slice), this can be used to remove the test.

Comment: I didn't work it out in full but the keys will be a sequence like start:stop:step and the values will be like start_:stop_:1, my idea was to calculate the starts and stops as functions of a,b,c,d and then just zip them up

Answer (score 2):

You could use dict comprehension for this:

```
dict = {i: i/c for i in range(a,b) if i%c == d}
```

Comment: Wow.! It's tie..!